# How to create Time with Hour+Minute+Seconds in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three var char values as

```
@hour = '18'
@minute = '25'
@seconds = '45'
```

I need output in the form of '18:25:45'

```
Select from Convert(Time,@hour+@minute+@seconds)
```

values in hour minute and seconds coming from SSRS report drop down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implicit conversion is not allowed. One solution could be to organise the format as a string and then convert to time as below.

```
declare @hour smallint = '18'
declare @minute smallint = '25'
declare @seconds smallint = '45'

declare @format varchar(8) = (select (CAST(@hour as varchar(2)) + ':'+ CAST(@minute as varchar(2))+':'+ CAST(@seconds as varchar(2))))

select CAST(@format as time)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can 'add-up' the values from zero, like this:

```
declare @hour smallint = 18
declare @minute smallint = 25
declare @seconds smallint = 45
declare @result time

SELECT @result =  DATEADD(hour, @hour, DATEADD(minute, @minute, DATEADD(second, @seconds, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this 24-H date format, It will Work.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS TimeResult
```

Comment: What's the 108 argument in this example?